# Add a custom plugin to AstroNvim

Tags: neovim, packer, astronvim

How to add a custom plugin to the `astronvim` distribution? `astronvim` uses the `Packer` plugin manager, but I cannot find the default syntax for `Packer` which looks like this:

```
return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
end)
```

Is there a special way to do this in `astronvim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special way indeed.

1. At first you have to clone the `user_example`-directory from the project's github page.

`git clone https://github.com/AstroNvim/user_example ~/.config/nvim/lua/user`

2. Inside `user` there is a `init.lua` where you can make your own custom changes.
3. Search for plugins with `/plugins` and you will find a section where you can add custom plugins which looks like this.

```
  plugins = {
    init = { 
      -- You can also add new plugins here as well:
      -- Add plugins, the packer syntax without the "use"
      -- Custom colorscheme dracula plugin
      { "Mofiqul/dracula.nvim" },
    },
  },
```

Although `Packer` is used, in `astrovim` you specify wanted plugins with `{ "<user_name>/plugin.nvim" },` inside the `init`.

4. At last, use the `PackerSync`-Command to download and install you wanted plugin.

Comment: I don't have a `user_example` directory in my `~/.config/nvim/lua` directory.

Comment: Perhaps the `git clone` command above is wrapped to a 2nd line and you only copy-pasted the first line?  You want the whole command (ends with `.../lua/user`).